# Error Estimate of Vector Addition

Tags: vector, floating-point, numerical-analysis

Kahan, in [Cross](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/MathH110/Cross.pdf) on page 14, shows that the angle between the true cross product and the one calculated using floating point arithmetic degrades as the angle between the two crossed vectors approaches zero or π, this angle measuring the error in the floating point calculation of the normal to the plane spanned by the crossed vectors.  As the singularities are approached, the orthogonality of the floating point normal becomes more compromised.  According to Kahan, the error is:

|sin(∠(t_true, t_float ))| ≤ u+(2/√3)u|csc(∠(t_1, t_2 ))|

where t_true is true orthogonal vector after taking the cross product, t_1⊗t_2, to infinite precision, whereas t_float is the result of the cross product using floating point arithmetic and u is the unit round off.

My question: is there a similar inequality for the sum of two vectors.  That is, how far off from the true direction does the floating point vector sum get as the angle between the vectors to be added approaches zero or π?  In my particular application, the vectors will be unit length.

Edit: I should add that the vector that is the sum of the two vectors will be normalized.

Comment: Seems like this belongs on http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The sum of two vectors will be off by at most 1/2 ulp in each component.  This is because you compute the sum componentwise and that bound holds for floating-point addition.  If you're looking for a bound on something else that has to do with the sum, please say so.

Comment: Patrick, I thought about math.stackexchange.com but decided here as this is a floating point problem.

Comment: Tmyklebu, after normalizing the vector that is the sum of the two unit vectors, I want to calculate the maximum angle between the true vector and that produced by the floating point calculation.  I am looking to relate it to the error calculation Kahan gives for the cross product.

Comment: I don't think there will be much error relative to the input vectors in this calculation. However, the vectors are presumably the results of other calculations and conversions. The worst case will be if they are in almost, but not quite, opposite directions. The (small) sum will be dominated by their existing rounding error, which will be magnified when you normalize.

Comment: @dmbaker: You're worried about how wrong the angle is?  Are you absolutely certain that you have the correct input vectors or are you looking for something that takes into account error in the inputs?  (Note that subtraction of two nearly-equal floating-point numbers is *exact*; this may lead to an unreasonably tight bound if the vectors in your input are supposed to be something nearby.)

Comment: Patricia, there is some error in the input vectors.  They are calculated from polar coordinates.  I am trying to figure out how close to anti-parallel I can get before the error gets so great that it is unreasonable given the quality of the input data.  After normalization, unit direction vector is then scaled by a factor to get the point at the end.  The scaling is many orders of magnitude greater than unity so the position error may be significant.

Comment: Patricia (continued), I am looking for a cut off based on the length squared of the vector sum.  I have done this using the Kahan inequality.  When the squared length of the vector is approximately 1.1E-08 the sin of the error angle is approximately 5.0E-08 in double precision (the small sin approximation is about equal to the angle so is a nice measure).  This is much better precision than any of my input polar data.

Comment: Tmyklebu, No, the angle will tell me how far off the true and calculated are as the Kahan inequality does for the cross product vector.  My guess is that the cross product error is higher than the summation error.  I could use the cross product error as an upper bound for a given set of data, but I am trying to do a little better.

Comment: @dmbaker: If I'm getting you right, you want a bound on the angle between the rounded `fl(v-w)` and the true `v+deltav-w-deltaw`, where `deltav` and `deltaw` represent errors in the input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take `c` to be the computed `v-w` and `e` is the difference between `c` and what you wanted to compute, namely `(v+deltav) - (w+deltaw)`.  Here, `e` accounts for both roundoff error in computation and approximation error in your input.

Take `r` to be the ratio `||e|| / ||c||`.  This must be less than one, otherwise we simply have no idea where the true solution is.

By trigonometry, the angle between `c` and `c+e` is `arccos(c^T (c+e) / sqrt(c^T c (c+e)^T (c+e))) = arccos((1 + alpha r) / sqrt(1 + 2 alpha r + r^2)`, where `-1 <= alpha <= 1` is the ratio of `e^T c` to `sqrt(c^T c e^T e)`.  The cosine of the angle between `c` and `c+e` is minimised when `alpha` is exactly `-r`, at which point the angle is `arccos(sqrt(1 - r^2)) = arcsin(r)`.

You can get the same result from the law of sines.  Given a `c` and a bound on `||e||/||c||`, the points that can reasonably be `c+e` lie on a circle centred at `c` of radius `||e||`.  The worst `c+e` will be on the boundary and the line from the origin to the worst `c+e` will make a right angle with the line from `c+e` to `c`.  Thus the angle opposite `c` is a right angle.  By the law of sines, then, `||e|| / sin(theta) = ||c||`, from which the same result follows.

Comment: tmyklebu, Thank you for your insight.  Questions: 1) Is "e" a constant, 2) if no input error exists would "e" be the unit round off? 3) Is "c" unit length?

Comment: If no input error exists, you can get a far stronger bound here because Sterbenz's theorem tells you that no error is incurred in any component whose magnitude is significantly reduced.  `e` is not a constant; it's a vector that is the sum of the roundoff error (up to half an ulp in each component) with the error in the input (application-dependent).  Put another way, `e` is the vector difference between the thing you wanted to compute and the thing you actually computed.

Comment: tmyklebu, my original question was for the addition of two unit vectors, but your answer refers to the subtraction of the vectors v-w.  Does this make a difference in the error bound?